# Mongoose update $lte wont match nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It keeps returning with zero nodes updated even though the cluster.node's health is 1.

```
var conditions =  { 'nodes.$.health': { $lte: 4  }}
  , update = { $inc: { 'nodes.$.health': 1  }}
  , options = { multi: true };

cluster.update(conditions, update, options, callbackdb);

function callbackdb (err, numberAffected) {
  console.log(numberAffected);
};
```

Comment: change `nodes.$.health` to `nodes.health` in the `find()` part, i.e, the `conditions` variable, of the query. The `$` positional operator cannot be used to match any sub document fields, but can be used to only update the matching sub document.

Comment: @BatScream Correct! Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?